# The ad does not appear in the published app

Tags: ios, admob, app-store

A few days ago, my app was published on the app store. At the development stage, I added an advertisement in the form of a regular banner. With the test identifier, the test ad was displayed successfully. But with a real identifier, the app was showing a blank banner. I read that in iOS apps with real identifiers , Ads are not shown until publication in App Store. But even a few days after the publication, the advertisement is still not shown. How to fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq7Ks.png)

Comment: Which Ads platform are you using?

Comment: I use google admob

Answer (score 0):

Google Admob was having some trouble lately, but normally it must take around 1~2 days for the ads to be provided and it always depending on the user location, and check in the phone settings if the Ad limitations are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Until you link the app from the AppStore in the app settings within abmob, the ads will not be shown. Normally Google takes about 7-10 days from the publication in the AppStore, to allow you to select the app from the AppStore within the admob settings, but in my case, with my last application it has already been 2 weeks and it still does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14.
You may need to add `SKAdNetworkItems` key to your app's .plist.